# Determining the maximum number of simultaneous touches possible on an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch, ios

Is there a way to find out the maximum number of simultaneous touches on an iOS device (iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad) ? I've read here and there that iPhone can handle 5 while the iPad can handle 11, but I haven't found an official way (through a function call, say) to confirm this.

Comment: In the Stanford classes on iTunes U it was said to be "enough, because the maximum would outnumber your fingercount".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By testing it!  See here for videos and source: http://mattgemmell.com/2010/05/09/ipad-multi-touch

There's no public API to request that information from the hardware.

Comment: Do you happen to know a way to increase the limit from 5 to 10 on an iPhone? I need it for my iOS game.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone can register 5 touch points on its tiny display, don't know about iPad.

Having said that, I wouldn't count on the numbers that you find empirically, because this information is not documented nor there is an api for it.

One good reason I can think of is the reduced touch sensor accuracy as the number of touch points increase.